# Webfonts not formatted correctly?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I'm using webfonts via css and I've noticed that the font I chose BPreplay looks different on the web than on my localhost... like some of the letters aren't properly shaped... why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this same thing... I'll make an assumption here, if I am wrong then let me know: You're running Visual Studio...

Visual Studio doesn't deploy a web app (by default) on your local host the same way that IIS does... By default it uses it's own Development Server.

If you will right click on your web app project -> Web Tab -> Servers Section

In there you can tell your project to run in a local iis instance instead of the VS Development Server. If you'll change your settings to this, you should get a consistent result between local and deployed.  Again, I am speculating that you're developing w/ VS, because I see this same thing w/ these circumstances.

Comment: +1 Correct, it uses a built-in server called Cassini. This could possibly account for the difference.

Comment: i'm using django 1.3 on webfaction/linux

Comment: this didn't really help, but i switched webfonts to one that didn't act weird... so prob won't need this post anymore, although, I would like an answer...